# sharing photo from android app

Tags: android, share, wallpaper, whatsapp

I have developed one wallpaper application in which I want to add share button to share a photo on whatsapp. Here is my code( but that code is only for any text msg) I want to share a photo.

Please respond with the code where in I can select a wallpaper from my application and send to whatsapp's particular contact.

```
case R.id.save:
        InputStream y11 = getResources().openRawResource(to);
        Bitmap b11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(y11);
        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("image/*");

        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp.android");
        waIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, to);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
waIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

with

```
waIntent.setType("image/png");
```

Comment: i have just edited my code. in which i put image/* but it could not work.

Comment: What is "to" here : `waIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, to);`

Comment: ok. "to" is my image source. int to=R.drawable.1 or R.drawable.2 etc

Comment: if i run this above code i get an error that "no application can perform this action".. where ever i have whatsapp in my device

Comment: try image/png instead of image/*

Comment: You need to pass the URI in this line not the Bitmap : `waIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, to);`

Comment: i did not get you as I m a learner. can you suggest me a code?

Answer (score 0):

the package name is wrong. try: `com.whatsapp`
and this code is to share image via whatsapp

```
private void shareIt(Uri uri) {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
        sharingIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Shared via my app");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share with"));
    }
```